# Show relation b/w nodes in D3 tree graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 js library and eveything is working fine . But I need some enhancement and I don't know If d3 library already support the same or not.

Actually I want to show inter-relation b/w two nodes using de , you will get better idea from the image I have added.

[image]

I am using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033) library right now to show graph .The enhancement which I am looking for is possible using same library or I have to use any other library.

Answer (score 0):

I found one library which suits my needs , it is a multiple parent library.
http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/6afc2ecb05b191359862

I hope it helps someone else too